# How can -1 divided by 2 result in -1? (bitwise operation >>)

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I was surprised to see that -1 divided by 2 using bitwise operations results -1.

I was expecting 0 to be returned.

Just like when you divide 1 or -1 by 2 the decimal part is removed and we get zero.
This might have to do with Two's complement but is just a guess and a guess that I don't fully understand.

can somebody explain it?

-1 >> 1 = -1

-1 / 2  = 0

```
 public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println(-1 >> 1);
      System.out.println(-1 / 2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Java has **two** right bit-shift operators. `System.out.println(-1 >>> 1);`

Comment: The second problem is just an integer division. The result of int / int is int.

Comment: Right-shifting is not equal to division for negative numbers, and is compiler-specific... at least in C. I'd presume the same holds for Java, or just stick to "right-shifting is not same as division for negative numbers"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative number in java is representated using a notation called [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). If we assume the size of the signed integer is 8. you can think of 2's complement like this

```
2 will be  00000010
1 will be  00000001
0 will be  00000000
-1 will be 11111111 (Count in reverse from max)
-2 will be 11111110
-3 will be 11111101
```

(Actually in java the size of `int` is 4 bytes)

`>>` this is signed bitwise right shift operator. according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) it fills 0 on the leftmost position for positive numbers and for negative numbers it will fill the same position with 1.

Which means shifting -1 any number of time gives -1 only.

```
11111111 >> 1 = 11111111
```

This is because of the [Non-equivalence of arithmetic right shift and division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift#Non-equivalence_of_arithmetic_right_shift_and_division) meaning for negative numbers division by 2 and right shift should not be considered equal in all cases

Comment: I @k4vin thanks this issue was not cause only in -1 but to all odd numbers.
the fix is to use (oddnumber + 1) >> 1;